# Sort key pair value array in TypeScript

Tags: sorting, typescript, dynamic-arrays

[image]Following is dynamic array in TypeScript and I want to sort it by activation date in descending order.

```
notificationList = [];

notificationList = [ {"Id:11", "ActivationDate":"29-Jan-2018"},
{"Id:21", "ActivationDate":"22-Jan-2018"},
{"Id:8", "ActivationDate":"01-Feb-2018"},
{"Id:10", "ActivationDate":"25-Jan-2018"},
{"Id:12", "ActivationDate":"24-Jan-2018"},
{"Id:05", "ActivationDate":"28-Jan-2018"},
{"Id:04", "ActivationDate":"24-Jan-2018"},
]
```

I am sorting using below code but it's not giving me expected output.

```
this.notificationList = this.notificationList.sort(function(a, b): any {
              const dateA = new Date(a['ActivationDate']);
              const dateB = new Date(b['ActivationDate']);
              console.log('dateA -' + dateA);
              console.log('dateB -' + dateB);
              console.log(dateB > dateA);
              return dateB > dateA; //sort by date decending
          });
```

Any suggestion or input ?

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes Arvind. It's looks same as what I given above. Although I tried your given code as well but no luck. I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: what you tried using my code can you edit the plunker in it and give me link so i can work on it and help you more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback to sort should [return a number](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) :

```
let notificationList = [
    { "Id": 11, "ActivationDate": "29 Jan 2018" },
    { "Id": 21, "ActivationDate": "22 Jan 2018" },
    { "Id": 8, "ActivationDate": "01 Feb 2018" },
    { "Id": 10, "ActivationDate": "25 Jan 2018" },
    { "Id": 12, "ActivationDate": "24 Jan 2018" },
    { "Id": 5, "ActivationDate": "28 Jan 2018" },
    { "Id": 4, "ActivationDate": "24 Jan 2018" },
];

notificationList = notificationList.sort(function (a, b): any {
    const dateA = new Date(a['ActivationDate']);
    const dateB = new Date(b['ActivationDate']);
    return dateB > dateA ? 1 : dateB < dateA ? -1 : 0; //sort by date decending
});
```

**Note** The date format you use is [not officially supported](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) and will only work in Chrome. I removed the `-` from the dates to convert the dates to a supported format.

Comment: I don't why it's not taking effect. attached screenshot after applying above how it looks like. Don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Your solution is working fine in Chrome but it's not working in IE and FireFox. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Sorry not at the PC anymore.. I'll check tomorrow of it isn't too late..

Comment: @PushkarRathod The problem is not with the sorting it's with the date format, your date format is not officially supported: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp. Changed the answer to use a format supported across browsers

Comment: I can't change the date format because it's a requirement. The date format should be DD-MMM-YYYY only. Let me know what can be done to support in all browser.

Comment: You can replace the `-` with ` ` : `const dateA = new Date(a['ActivationDate'].replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'), ' '));
    const dateB = new Date(b['ActivationDate'].replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'), ' '));
`. Or you can use something like `momentjs` to do advanced parsing

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is wrong you should be having `<` instead of `<`

```
this.notificationList.sort((a, b)=> {
  let dateA = new Date(a['ActivationDate']);
  let dateB =  new Date(b['ActivationDate']);
  return dateA < dateB; // sort by descending
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3TP5BpF28bGWLpFmYGwy?p=preview)**

Comment: If I use above mentioned code it throws me following error. Argument of type '(a: any, b: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: any, b: any) => number'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: Argument of type '(a: any, b: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: any, b: any) => number'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: @PushkarRathod can you update it to post?. are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: No. I can't do team viewer. But I can mail the whole object which I want to sort. Can you share me your id please ?

Comment: reach me out in fb @ aravind2109 we can work from there on

Comment: @Arvind. Your give solution works only in Chrome. Is there anyway to fix them to work in IE and FireFox. I my Chrome is not user's target browser. They will use application in IE and FireFox only. Let me know if you have any fix for this which work in IE and FixeFox both.

Comment: I changed the date format and it's working fine in the IE and FireFox as well.